# How to install Indiago ROS in Ubuntu14.04.4 (trusty LTS)?

Tags: ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All:
I am new about ROS but middle in linux.
Here is one problem that encountered during the installation of Indiago ROS.

The main steps of installation are following the offical site as shown below:
http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu

First , I tried to install Indiago-desktop-full by typing the following commands below:
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
which shows the following messages:
paultsai@paultsai-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
[sudo] password for paultsai:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-indigo-perception but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

In order to fix the dependency issues, I tries to first install ros-indigo-desktop by typing the following commands
paultsai@paultsai-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-indigo-desktop : Depends: ros-indigo-common-tutorials but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-indigo-geometry-tutorials but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-indigo-robot but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-indigo-ros-tutorials but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-indigo-rqt-common-plugins but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-indigo-rqt-robot-plugins but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-indigo-visualization-tutorials but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-indigo-viz but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I have tried serveral methods like sudo apt-get install -f and sudo apt-get install libsformat1
they seems does not work for me .

paultsai@paultsai-VirtualBox:/mnt/SHARE$ sudo apt-get install libsdformat1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libsdformat1 : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.54.0 but it is not installable
Depends: libboost-regex1.54.0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Finally , I also try follow the steps to install those packages first by typing the following commands
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-dev-lts-utopic mesa-common-dev-lts-utopic libxatracker-dev-lts-utopic libopenvg1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgles1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgbm-dev-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic

paultsai@paultsai-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-dev-lts-utopic mesa-common-dev-lts-utopic libxatracker-dev-lts-utopic libopenvg1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgles1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgbm-dev-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-dev-lts-utopic
E: Unable to locate package mesa-common-dev-lts-utopic
E: Unable to locate package libxatracker-dev-lts-utopic
E: Unable to locate package libopenvg1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic
E: Unable to locate package libgles2-mesa-dev-lts-utopic
E: Unable to locate package libgles1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic
E: Unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic
E: Unable to locate package libgbm-dev-lts-utopic
E: Unable to locate package libegl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic

How can I fix these dependency issues and Error messages when installing ROS-indigo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246462/how-to-install-indiago-ros-in-ubuntu14.04.4-(trusty-lts)?/) by [PaulTsai111](https://answers.ros.org/users/28338/paultsai111/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure you are running Ubuntu 14.04.**4**? I recently tried to install ROS on 14.04.**5** and got some similar errors to yours. I had to go back to 14.04.4 and everything went fine.

---

Originally posted by [OMC](https://answers.ros.org/users/27334/omc/) with karma: 74 on 2016-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PaulTsai111](https://answers.ros.org/users/28338/paultsai111/) on 2016-10-27**:
I have checked my Ubuntu it is really for Ubuntu14.04.4 (as shown below)

paultsai@paultsai-VirtualBox:~$lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available. 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu 
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.4 
LTS Release: 14.04 
Codename: trusty 
paultsai@paultsai-VirtualBox:~$